# Spinnaker GateWay EndPoint

Tags: docker, kubernetes, continuous-integration, spinnaker

I'm working for a spinnaker for create a new CD pipeline.

I've deployed halyard in a docker container on my computer, and also deployed spinnaker from  it to the Google Kubernetes Engine.

After all of them, I've prepared a new ingress yaml file, shown as below.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: jenkins-cloud
  namespace: spinnaker
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: spin-deck
          servicePort: 9000
```

After accessing the spinnaker UI via a public IP, I got an error, shown as below.

```
Error fetching applications. Check that your gate endpoint is accessible.
```

After all of them, I've checked the docs about it and I've run some commands shown as below.

I've checked the service data on my K8S cluster.

```
spin-deck          NodePort    10.11.245.236   <none>        9000:32111/TCP   1h
spin-gate          NodePort    10.11.251.78    <none>        8084:31686/TCP   1h
```

### For UI

```
hal config security ui edit --override-base-url "http://spin-deck.spinnaker:9000"
```

### For API

```
hal config security api edit --override-base-url "http://spin-gate.spinnaker:8084"
```

After running these commands and redeploying spinnaker, the error repeated itself.

How can I solve the problem of accessing the spinnaker gate from the UI?

Comment: Could you check if the services spin-deck and spin-gate have correct endpoints? "kubectl describe svc spin-deck|spin-gate -n correct_namespace" If you see no endpoints you need to check if corresponding pods are healthy using "kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide"

Comment: try following this. I was able to access Spinnaker via ingress.
https://medium.com/faun/deploy-spinnaker-onto-k8s-and-access-via-ingress-18ca82c76046

Answer (score 0):

`--override-base-url` should be populated without port.

Comment: @FZs Actually it does, the issue is caused by misconfiguration